# Azure Cosmos DB Set collection TTL as - on (No Default) via C# code

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I am looking for an option to set my Cosmos DB collection TTL to ON but with no default.

Here I want to control expiry time at the document level. I see if I set default Time in collection level it will override the time mentioned in document level.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Basically, I can set this in Data Explorer but not sure how I can set up through C# code.

From this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live,

I see I can set -1  (Expiry off) or n for a number of seconds for expiry.

[image]

Comment: If I am not mistaken, here're the values: `Off` - `0`; `On (no default)` - `-1`, `On` - `Some valid numeric value indicating seconds`.

Comment: @GauravMantri `Off` is an illegal value for TTL in CosmosDB. TTL is a nullable int so `Off` is `null`

Comment: @GauravMantri  Yes, you are right. my miss understanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So just to clarify.

- When DefaultTimeToLive is null then your Time to Live is `Off`
- When DefaultTimeToLive is -1 then your Time to Live setting is `On (No default)`
- When DefaultTimeToLive has any other Int value (except 0) your Time to Live setting is `On`

Comment: Thanks, I miss understood the definition.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify/expand on @Nick s answer
Here is the link to Microsofts docs, I also included the info for documents TTL as it might be good to acknowledge at the same time

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.document.timetolive?view=azure-dotnet#remarks)

**DefaultTTL for the collection**

- If missing (or set to null), documents are not deleted automatically.
- If present and the value is set to "-1" = infinite – documents don’t
  expire by default
- If present and the value is set to some number ("n") – documents
  expire "n" seconds after last modification

**TTL for the documents:**

Property is **applicable only if DefaultTTL is present for the parent collection**.

- Overrides the DefaultTTL value for the parent collection.

**Note:** 
The final time-to-live policy of a document is evaluated after consulting the collection's DefaultTimeToLive.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.documentcollection.defaulttimetolive?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_DocumentCollection_DefaultTimeToLive

Answer (score 0):

When you create your document, you can add the TTL to it.

[Setting TTL on a documen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live#setting-ttl-on-a-document)